# Webdriver 3.1.0.0 Firefox 47.0.2 and Geckodriver 0.17.0 unable to change URL

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, selenium-webdriver

I am using C# 4.6.2 in Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 on Windows 7 Enterprise SP1 x64

I updated to Webdriver 3.1.0.0, Firefox 46.0.2 and Geckodriver 0.17.0 and when I run my tests now geckodriver and Firefox opens, but setting WebDriver's (FirefoxDriver) Url property does nothing. Getting the Url property's value seems to always be the string

```
"System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]"
```

even if I manually go to a URL in the browser window.

I have tried both the 32 bit and the 64 bit version of Geckodriver  and had exactly the same problem with both.

The code that the test is running is:

```
private readonly string rootUrl = "https://localhost:44388/Home/CaseList";
```

...

```
WebDriver.Url = rootUrl;
```

If I use the immediate window I have the following result

```
Browser.WebDriver.Url="http://www.google.com"
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.WebException' in System.dll
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.WebException' in System.dll
"http://www.google.com"
```

Browser is our own static class with the property

```
public static IWebDriver WebDriver
```

If I create a new FirefoxDriver using the default constructor in the immediate window it opens successfully, but I get this feedback

```
webDriver = new FirefoxDriver()
Exception thrown: 'System.Net.Sockets.SocketException' in System.dll
{OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox.FirefoxDriver}
    ApplicationCache: '((OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver)(webDriver = new FirefoxDriver())).ApplicationCache' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
    Capabilities: {Capabilities [BrowserName=, IsJavaScriptEnabled=False, Platform=Any, Version=]}
    CommandExecutor: {OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DriverServiceCommandExecutor}
    CurrentWindowHandle: "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]"
    FileDetector: {OpenQA.Selenium.DefaultFileDetector}
    HasApplicationCache: false
    HasLocationContext: false
    HasWebStorage: false
    IsMarionette: true
    IsSpecificationCompliant: true
    Keyboard: {OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteKeyboard}
    LocationContext: '((OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver)(webDriver = new FirefoxDriver())).LocationContext' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
    Mouse: {OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteMouse}
    OpenQA.Selenium.Internal.IActionExecutor.IsActionExecutor: true
    PageSource: "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]"
    SessionId: {OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.SessionId}
    Title: "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]"
    Url: "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.Object]"
    WebStorage: '((OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver)(webDriver = new FirefoxDriver())).WebStorage' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
    WindowHandles: '((OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver)(webDriver = new FirefoxDriver())).WindowHandles' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException'
    appCache: null
    capabilities: {Capabilities [BrowserName=, IsJavaScriptEnabled=False, Platform=Any, Version=]}
    executor: {OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.DriverServiceCommandExecutor}
    fileDetector: {OpenQA.Selenium.DefaultFileDetector}
    keyboard: {OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteKeyboard}
    locationContext: null
    mouse: {OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteMouse}
    sessionId: {OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.SessionId}
    storage: null
```

Any ideas on how to fix these issues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Selenium IRC found out that I needed to update Firefox again (to 54) and update Webdriver again ( to 3.3) now it seems to be working OK again.